# Error to merge table with dplyr

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

I have a small issue with the function `inner_join()` from `dplyr`.
I have two tables `LatLong` and `data_stops`.

LatLong is:

```
>  str(LatLong) Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  43456 obs. of  3 variables:  $ Idindx  : num  1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 ...  $ latMean :
 num  54.8 54.8 54.8 54.8 54.8 ...  $ longMean: num  11.1 11.1 11.1
 11.1 11.1 ...
  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
  - attr(*, "vars")=List of 1   ..$ : symbol Idindx

> dput(head(LatLong))
structure(list(Idindx = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11), latMean = c(54.831033947613, 
54.8310100000107, 54.8309920000003, 54.8310145000011, 54.8310115000001, 
54.831043), longMean = c(11.1227872540957, 11.1227459999747, 
11.1227690000004, 11.1227944999961, 11.1228075000002, 11.1228525
)), .Names = c("Idindx", "latMean", "longMean"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

and data_stops is:

```
'data.frame':   2020 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Idindx          : num  1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 ...
 $ minTime         : POSIXct, format: "2008-06-01 00:07:16" "2008-06-01 08:44:42" "2008-06-01 08:50:18" "2008-06-01 08:56:45" ...
 $ maxTime         : POSIXct, format: "2008-06-01 08:40:25" "2008-06-01 08:46:33" "2008-06-01 08:52:43" "2008-06-01 08:58:44" ...
 $ duration_minutes:Class 'difftime'  atomic [1:2020] 513 2 2 2 1 1 3 3 6 7 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "mins"
 $ Ship            : num  NA NA NA  NA  NA   ...
 $ latMean         : num  54.8 54.8 54.8 54.8 54.8 ...
 $ longMean        : num  11.1 11.1 11.1 11.1 11.1 ...



 > dput(head(data_stops))
structure(list(Idindx = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11), minTime = structure(c(1212268036, 
1212299082, 1212299418, 1212299805, 1212300243, 1212300629), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), maxTime = structure(c(1212298825, 1212299193, 1212299563, 
1212299924, 1212300293, 1212300664), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
)), duration_minutes = structure(c(513, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1), units = "mins", class = "difftime"), 
    Ship = c(111111111, 111111111, 111111111, 111111111, 111111111, 
    111111111)), .Names = c("Idindx", "minTime", "maxTime", "duration_minutes", 
"Ship"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

When I tried to merge them following Idindx  I have the following error:

```
final_data<- inner_join(data_stops, LatLong)

Joining by: "Idindx"
Error in data.table::setkeyv(x, by$x) : 
  4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3
```

Here what I tried:

- update RStudio and the packages I use: no success
- to also use merge(LatLong,data_stops, by="Idindx"): no success
- to make sure that the two tables have the same format: as.data.table(): no success
- to make sure that Idindx is numerical for both of the table: no success

Finally with

```
final_data <- full_join(data_stops, LatLong, by="Idindx" )
```

It worked!

I would like to understand why `inner_join()` is not working here!

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe because `str(LatLong) Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame'`? Join functions take as arguments tbls

Comment: Thank you. I don´t reallt understant. With  ‘as.data.table()’ they both have the same ‘str()’ !

Comment: @Floni Can you edit your question with the result of `dput(head(LatLong))` and `dput(head(data_stops))`. I can try it then.

Comment: @Phil, this is done!

Comment: inner_join(data_stops, LatLong) works fine for me, using your example data.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data you posted (`dput()`) I had no problem joining the data with `dplyr::inner_join()`:

```
data_stops <- structure(list(Idindx = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11), minTime = structure(c(1212268036, 
                                                                                  1212299082, 1212299418, 1212299805, 1212300243, 1212300629), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                                         "POSIXt")), maxTime = structure(c(1212298825, 1212299193, 1212299563, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           1212299924, 1212300293, 1212300664), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
                                                                                                                                                                                           )), duration_minutes = structure(c(513, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1), units = "mins", class = "difftime"), 
                             Ship = c(111111111, 111111111, 111111111, 111111111, 111111111, 
                                      111111111)), .Names = c("Idindx", "minTime", "maxTime", "duration_minutes", 
                                                              "Ship"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

LatLong <- structure(list(Idindx = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11), latMean = c(54.831033947613, 
                                                                     54.8310100000107, 54.8309920000003, 54.8310145000011, 54.8310115000001, 
                                                                     54.831043), longMean = c(11.1227872540957, 11.1227459999747, 
                                                                                              11.1227690000004, 11.1227944999961, 11.1228075000002, 11.1228525
                                                                     )), .Names = c("Idindx", "latMean", "longMean"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                          -6L))

require("dplyr")
final_data <- inner_join(data_stops, LatLong, by = "Idindx")
head(final_data)

#   Idindx             minTime             maxTime duration_minutes      Ship
# 1      1 2008-05-31 22:07:16 2008-06-01 06:40:25         513 mins 111111111
# 2      3 2008-06-01 06:44:42 2008-06-01 06:46:33           2 mins 111111111
# 3      5 2008-06-01 06:50:18 2008-06-01 06:52:43           2 mins 111111111
# 4      7 2008-06-01 06:56:45 2008-06-01 06:58:44           2 mins 111111111
# 5      9 2008-06-01 07:04:03 2008-06-01 07:04:53           1 mins 111111111
# 6     11 2008-06-01 07:10:29 2008-06-01 07:11:04           1 mins 111111111
# (Truncated)
```

I didn't have any problem using `inner_join()` without specifying a key either. I suspect something in your environment had been modified and when using clean data it worked as intended.

As an aside, I'd avoid using different notations for naming objects in R (or any programming language): you mix camel case (`LatLong`) with using an underscore (`data_stops`). I'd use one or the other. I prefer underscore because I find it easier to scan, but it doesn't really matter.